# PDO insert statement not work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have problem with INSERT query. It returns false and doesn't inserting anything into the database.

I'm connected to database and other delete and update queries are working, but insert doesn't.

Here is my function which prepares and runs the insert query:

```
    Autoloader::Load('HandleDB/InsertDB');
    $insert = new InsertDB();
    echo "<p>data:</p>";
    var_dump($data);
    echo "<p>prepare</p>";
    var_dump($statment = $this->db->prepare($insert->Run($tableName,   $data)));
    echo "<p>prepare execute</p>";
    var_dump($insert->PrepareExecute($data));
    echo "<p>execute result:</p>";
    var_dump($statment->execute($insert->PrepareExecute($data)));
```

The result of this function is:

```
data:
array(3) { ["imie"]=> string(4) "user" ["login"]=> string(9) "loginname" ["password"]=> string(4) "pass" }
prepare

object(PDOStatement)#9 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(80) "INSERT INTO uzytkownik (imie, login, password) VALUES (:imie, :login, :password)" }
prepare execute

array(3) { ["imie"]=> string(4) "user" ["login"]=> string(9) "loginname" ["password"]=> string(4) "pass" }
execute result:

bool(false)
```

Comment: It might be useful if you told us what framework you were using

Comment: Can you post your table structure??

Comment: Table structure:

Table name "uzytkownik":

ID (autoincrement)
imie
login
haslo

Answer (score 0):

using MVC model with PDO, files written by my classmate. Other files and functions and queries works fine. Just this one.

This function gets $data as parameters from form.

Table structure:

Table name "uzytkownik":

- ID (autoincrement)
- imie
- login
- haslo